# Retrieve data from ServiceNow in MS chatbot

Tags: botframework, bots

Dears,

I want to integrate MS Chatbot to serviceNow.

End Users - ask questions in MS Chatbot (like ticket update or ticket creation) and MSbot responds accordingly.

Basically i want my MSbot to insert,get, update and delete data from servicenow.

Thanks

Comment: So have a look to Service Now API if any. Thanks

Comment: ya correct. Please let me know if you come across any help for me.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to develop your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Bot Service has no specific tutorials about how to integrate ServiceNow with a bot, but it can be done! ServiceNow has a REST API which is well documented in multiple places like [here](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=london&id=r_TableAPI-DELETE) and [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-application-development/page/build/applications/concept/api-rest.html).

If you want specific help with a specific issue regarding the Bot Framework, please feel free to ask a new question. And make sure to include the following information:

- Are you using the BotBuilder SDK v3 or v4?
- What coding language are you using?
- What channel is this bot for?

Answer (score 1):

Consuming service now api for data transfer i found here. same can be used for chat bot. I thought i should put this here.

http://sudiptachaudhari.com/create-incident-ticket-in-servicenow-using-csharp/

SNOW exposes REST API’s using which it can be integrated with our application. Please see SNOW Wiki reference for REST API at http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=REST_API#gsc.tab=0

REST API endpoint for creating incidents is :
https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident

where instance is your organization’s registered instance.

Thanks
Sanjeev Gautam